# OpenERP : How to diasable click on tree view records

Tags: odoo

Is there a way to disable the click on records from a tree view,so that the user can only see displayed fields (not details displayed when clicking)?

I've tried to put readonly="1".

**Edited**
I have a one2many field that i display in a tree view in my form view like this:

[image]

When some record is clicked in the tree view, details are displayed in a popup like this:

[image]

i don't wan't that this popup show up for anyone

Could someone please tell me is there a way to do it, maybe by using some css class?
Thank you

Comment: question: you have some users who are allowed to see the tree view, but not the form view?

Comment: I don't need and i don't want that the view to be displayed for any user

Comment: check this out. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43930866/odoo-9-how-to-restrict-one2many-to-not-show-a-form-view/46211973#46211973

Answer (score 2):

in the form and tree view you can add `create='false'` to disable the create button and `edit='false'` to disable the edit button.Also use editable="top" or editable="bottom" if you dont want the form view to popup. for example

```
<tree string="Sale Order" create="false" edit="false" editable="bottom">
...
...
...
</tree>
```

Comment: I edited my post so that my question become clear.please have a look at it

Answer (score 0):

I encounter this problem.
Try this.
Instead of

```
<field name="view_mode">tree,form</field>
```

change it to

```
<field name="view_mode">tree</field>
```

then no form view will show you and the tree view is not clickable anymore.